# Can foreign key be represented in terms of `check`?

Tags: postgresql

From the [postgresql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)

> A check constraint is the most generic constraint type.

How generic is `check`? Can foreign key be represented in terms of `check`? Thanks.

Comment: Could you link to the document where you saw this?

Comment: Did not understood your question... Would you elaborate further please? Maybe with an example of some sort

Comment: No. A check constraint can only check values in columns from the same row (and thus from the same table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) includes a more technical definition of CHECK constraints, including this sentence:

> Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row.

A CHECK constraint is generic in the sense that you can write an arbitrary expression, not just a column name or standard condition. A `NOT NULL` constraint could be expressed as a `CHECK` constraint, as could limits on the length of a `text` / `VarChar` column (i.e. `foo VarChar(10)` is roughly equivalent to `foo text CHECK (length(foo) <= 10)`).

However, the constraint is always *an assertion about a single row of the table*. Other types of constraint are used for other types of assertion:

- For asserting comparisons between rows in a table, there are `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, and `EXCLUSION` constraints.
- For asserting relationships between rows in different tables, or self-references between rows in a table, there are `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.